# Doing Sports while having Mono

Tags: sports, mononucleosis, spleen

Terribly sorry to bother you with this.

I'm a 28 year old bloke & last week I was diagnosed with infective mononucleosis. However I barely show any symptoms and I feel pretty good. I only went to visit the doctor because my throat was soar en my lymph nodes enlarged.
I had **NO** fever,joint pains, extreme fatigue.(I did feel slighty more tired the last couple of weeks). And my sports performances were going in a downward direction for the last month before the diagnosis.

Being very sportive (running and cycling), I didn't perform any sports for 2 weeks. However I actually feel good. A little bit more tired but not incapacitated.So I want to restart doing sports a soon as possible. I hoped to start next week with some light training (30 - 40km on the bike or running (max) 7 km at an easy pace).

I contacted my doctor(s) and they gave the green light. They said I should mainly listen to my own body. If it feels good, then I shouldn't hesitate to do some light activities.

However I did some reading. And some people said that...

```
If you start with sports too soon then the body won't fully recover. You 
might relapse a few months later. Or even worse, you won't ever fully 
recover! And the Mono (& slight fatigue) will remain lingering in my body
till the end of my days.
```

I contacted my doctor, sister (doctor aswell) & brother in law (sports doctor). they couldn't confirm this claim. They all said sports will increase the recovery time. And I should keep a close eye for an enlarged (more sensitive) spleen & liver. Does anyone here have any insight in this matter? Or can anyone debunk (hopefully) this claim?

Comment: Probably best to listen to your doctor(s) on this one. However, if you are still concerned about this, you could take that article to your doctor(s) and have them check into it.

Comment: I actually did. They said pretty much the same as Cibr_D. But sports is a big deal in my life and I wanted another opinion of someone with no personal ties to myself. It tend to be scaredy–cat sometimes... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are speaking about infective mononucleosis. No big deal - since your physician encourages you to excercise, that means that you've recovered and that your blood parameters and liver/spleen sizes are normal and not sensitive to touch. So do not worry and adhere to your physicians advice.

I could think only of one reason why these "claims" can sound true (they are not, ofc.). The thing is that the virus that causes the disease remains in your body dormant (it sleeps there, like herpes), and it can be reactivated latter in life, but the latter manifestations are minor in comparison to the first presentation. Also, another fact - the vast majority of the population has EBV (the virus behind mono) and nobody suffers from that.

Comment: It was indeed "infective mononucleosis" (I've edited the question). Thank you for reassuring me. I'm quite the scaredy–cat sometimes! I shouldn't read as much articles on the web, like i'm doing now.... :)